# Как выровнять элементы в одной строке?

Tags: выравнивание

```
<div id="location">
Текст
<input type="image" src="images/icons/location.png" width="15">
</div>
```

Мне нужно опустить картинку в строке на несколько пикселей.
Как это правильно делается?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div id="location">
Текст
<input type="image" src="http://reznik.kiev.ua/Album/d/1710-1/1db99d7d7357.jpg" width="15">
</div>
<div id="location">
Текст
<input style="vertical-align:middle" type="image" src="http://reznik.kiev.ua/Album/d/1710-1/1db99d7d7357.jpg" width="15">
</div>
```